# How to extract number of occurances of a reponse string in Jmeter and fail the test if the occurances does not match a number?

Tags: jmeter, assertions, beanshell

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of a response in Jmeter and if the count is not equal to 4, the test should fail.

How can i do that?

I used this in beanshell assertion:

```
Import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

int matches = StringUtils.countMatches(new String(data), "itemname"); 
vars.put("ItemNameVar_matchNr", String.valueOf(matches));
assert matches == 5;
```

It. is not working. It shows error:

> Typed variable declaration : Undefined argument: data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't have `data` in the Beanshell Assertion, there is a pre-defined variable `ResponseData` which is byte array.
2. You don't have `assert` in Beanshell, you have `Failure` pre-defined boolean which indicates whether sampler(s) in scope should be successful or not.
3. Full code:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

   int matches = StringUtils.countMatches(new String(ResponseData), "itemname"); 
   vars.put("ItemNameVar_matchNr", String.valueOf(matches));
   Failure = matches != 5;
   ```
4. References:

   - [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion)
   - [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: Thanks! this works!  Is there any way to access email via jmeter? I want to check the language of the email which i get...

Comment: [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler). Check [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for details. Assertions and PostProcessors can be applied to the Mail Reader Sampler normally.

Comment: Hi, i tried to implement it. But in the response, i am getting this http://imgur.com/0FP2p7c    how to get the actual message instead of folders?

Comment: How it is connected to the original question?

Comment: Try restarting JMeter, it looks like you have a problem with View Results Tree listener